# Is it possible to redirect Cloudflare's pages url to the main domain (from someurl.pages.dev to someurl.com)?

Tags: seo, redirects, google-index, cloudflare

Is it possible to redirect `example.pages.dev` to `example.com` using Cloudflare's DNS dashboard or pages?

So basically what I want is if someone visits `example.pages.dev`, the person should be redirected to `example.com`.

Note: `example.com` is pointing to `example.pages.dev` via `CNAME` entry inside Cloudflare's DNS dashboard already. Please also note that `example.pages.dev` is generated by Cloudflare's pages and is not in our control.

Please also clarify if Google will index the pages as duplicate? Because they'll be accessible from the URL generated by Cloudflare Pages on sub-domain and they'll also be available on main domain.

Will Google indexing these two pages and detect them as duplicates?

- `example.com/some-page`
- `example.pages.dev/some-page`

Comment: Remember that `.dev` TLD, as all Google TLDs, is "special" in the sense that it is included in the HSTS preloading list, which means browsers will only attempt HTTPS connection to it, and never HTTP, which in turn also means you need to have a proper certificate in place, and that happens BEFORE any kind of HTTP level redirections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been asked and answered in the Cloudflare pages forum: [Cloudflare Pages, custom domain - General - Cloudflare Community](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-pages-custom-domain/289453).

The answer as of July 2021 was that functionality for hiding the `pages.dev` domain by redirecting to the custom domain isn't available.  Instead you should use [rel canonical link tags](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-link-method) in the head of every page of your site to tell search engines which of the duplicate URLs is your preferred URL.

Having your site available on an alternate domain shouldn't hurt your SEO, especially if you use canonical tags.  When Google encounters duplicate content it typically chooses one of the two duplicate URLs to index and ignores the other.  With canonical meta tags, you can ensure that Google chooses the correct variant.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: Thanks for answering it quickly